# Why this function is giving unexpected result?

Tags: c

I was trying to co
So, I don't understand the reason why my compiler is not letting me take input when the convhex() is called from the main. It's directly printing some result.. I don't understand this.
Here's the code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <String.h>
void convhex();
void convert(int no, int base);
int checkValid(int base,int no);
// function prototyping done here

void convhex()
{
    char ch[10];
    int dec=0;
    int i, res;
    printf("Enter the hexadecimal number \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", ch);

    // print in decimal
    for(i=strlen(ch)-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(ch[i]>65)
            res=ch[i]-65+10;
        else
            res=ch[i]-48;
        //printf("%d", res);
        dec=dec+pow(16,strlen(ch)-(i+1))*res;
    }
    printf("\nThe number in decimal is %d \n", dec);
}
int checkValid(int base,int no)
{
    int rem;
    //flag;
//    flag=0;
    while(no>0)
    {
        rem=no%10;
        if(rem>base)
        {
            //flag=1;
            //break;
            return 0;
        }
        no/=10;
    }
    return 1;
    /*
    if(flag==1)
        printf("Invalid Input");
    else
        printf("Valid Input");
        */
}

void convert(int no, int base)
{
    int temp, mod, sum=0, i=0;
    temp=no;
    while(temp>0)
    {
        mod=temp%10;
            temp=temp/10;
            sum=sum+pow(base,i)*mod;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n The number in base 10 is %d", sum);
}
int main()
{
    int base, no;
    printf("Enter the base \n");
    scanf("%d", &base);
    if(base==16)
        convhex();
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the number \n");
        scanf("%d", &no);
        printf("You have entered %d", no);
        if(checkValid(base, no))
        convert(no, base);
    }


    return 0;
}

// up until now our program can work with any base from 0-10 but not hexadecimal
// in case of hex, we have A-F
```

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: It displays something like this in the command prompt
http://puu.sh/7Lwa8.png

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", ch);`

Comment: Thank you @BLUEPIXY. It worked out just fine :D 
May you explain the the operation that goes behind the scene as well?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &base);` : remain newline. then do `scanf("%[^\n]", ch);` : Input fails because it does not accept the new line. `" %[^\n]"` : To consume white space to put a space before parameter (`%`).

Comment: also should be `if(ch[i]>=65)`. (`if(ch[i]>='A')`)

Comment: Suggestions: 1) `scanf("%9s", ch);` 2) `'A'` for 65 and `'0'` for 48

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` in `convhex` is reading the `\n` left by the `scanf` in `main`.
Try this

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", ch);  
        ^ An extra space will eat any number of white-spaces.
```

Comment: `scanf` has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: @YvesDubois; I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, some of it looks kinda regular expression-ish, but `scanf` does not use regular expressions. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: The terminology might be wrong, but the fix is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove the `%[^\n]` from `scanf` in `connhex` to change it to:

```
scanf("%s", ch)
```

or you could do what haccks suggested in the above post.

Comment: You might want to explain *why*, but this fix makes more sense than using `[^\n]` anyway.

Comment: the `%` conversion discards the initial `white spaces` in the input